# How to allow whitespaces in tag names using django-tagging-0.3.1?

Tags: python, django, tagging, django-tagging

I'm using the [django-tagging-0.3.1](https://github.com/selwyn/codeshare/tree/master/thirdparty/django-tagging-0.3.1) package to tag all the articles in my website. But I just found that this package seems not to support whitespace in tag name, which means when a tag name has whitespace in it and you use the function it provides, `TaggedItem.objects.get_by_model`, to search all the articles with this tag, you will get an empty list. But actually I checked my server and the tag name is shown and associated with the corresponding articles correctly. So is there any way I can configure to make the space-contained-tag search work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the [`get_tag_list`](https://github.com/selwyn/codeshare/blob/master/thirdparty/django-tagging-0.3.1/tagging/utils.py#L142) utility function, which is called by `get_by_model`. If passed a string (such as `'my tag with spaces'`), it will return the following query:

```
Tag.objects.filter(name__in=parse_tag_input(tags))
```

Unfortunately, the [`parse_tag_input`](https://github.com/selwyn/codeshare/blob/master/thirdparty/django-tagging-0.3.1/tagging/utils.py#L18) function **assumes that space-separated words are different tags**, so it will assert that you are searching for the tags `['my', 'tag', 'with', 'spaces']`, which will of course not return anything.

Later in the `get_tag_list` function, there's a check to see if the input is a list/tuple:

```
elif isinstance(tags, (types.ListType, types.TupleType)):
    ...
```

The code following it **does not call parse_tag_input** (I guess it [assumes that each string within the list/tuple is a fully-formed tag](https://github.com/selwyn/codeshare/blob/master/thirdparty/django-tagging-0.3.1/tagging/utils.py#L182)).

**TL;DR:**
Thus, I believe that if you pass a tuple or a list containing the tag name, it will correctly find it.

```
TaggedItem.object.get_by_model(MyModel, ['my tag with spaces'])
```